# Get the Week Number between two Dates Pandas

Tags: python, date, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a basic code snippet that I need to recreate in pandas:

```
import datetime as dt
date1 = dt.date(2016,10,10)
date2 = dt.date.today()
print('Week#', round((date2 - date1).days / 7 +.5))
# output: Week# 36
```

I have a `datetime64[ns]` datatype column and I cannot crack it. Using this basic example I'm stumped:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
dfp = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [dt.date(2016,10,6)]})
dfp['A'] = pd.to_datetime(dfp['A'])

def week(col):
    print((col.dt.date -  dt.date(2015, 10, 6)))

week(dfp['A']) #output: 366 days
```

When I try re-creating the week number calculation I'm running into multiple errors: `print((col.dt.date -  dt.date(2015, 10, 6)).days)` returns `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'`

I'd like to try and solve this on my own so I can learn from the pain.

How do I return the pandas column values in terms of "number of days" or as an `int` like using the first calculation in the first code snippet? (ie, instead of `366 days`, just `366`)

If you're feeling adventurous how could i get the `Week# xxx` output in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget `.dt`:

```
dfp = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [date2]})
dfp['A'] = pd.to_datetime(dfp['A'])
print (dfp)

print (((dfp['A'].dt.date -  dt.date(2016, 10, 10)).dt.days / 7 + .5).round().astype(int))
0    36
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Comment: This works for my small example. But I'm getting `IndexError: unsupported iterator index` for my bigger example on my actual project: `print(((df1['Referral Date'].dt.date - dt.date(2016,10,10)).dt.days / 7 + .5).round().astype(int))`. The dtype of Referral Date is a confirmed `datetime64[ns]`. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, for me works nice `dfp = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [dt.date.today(), dt.date(2016,12,10), dt.date(2016,11,10)]})`. For you not?

Comment: Also `print(((df1['Referral Date'].dt.date - dt.date(2016,10,10)).dt.days` works with your real data?

Comment: Your First comment runs fine, When I try to run the second snip of code, I once again get `IndexError: unsupported iterator index`

Comment: Hmm, if reset index, still same problme? `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Resetting the index did not work, still same error :(

Comment: What is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())`

Comment: Python 3.6.0, `Pandas` 0.19.2, `numpy` 1.13

Comment: Is possible upgrade? Maybe bug. For me in `0.20.2` it works nice.

Comment: Tried to upgrade, now `numpy` is all out of whack. I'll get back to you when I fix the issue. `ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']` Even though it is installed. Give me a few moments. Thank you!

Comment: This is the first time that a version issue has impacted me. Works great it `0.20.2`

Comment: Supeeer, glad can help!